# how to get results from a mysql database using three parameters like (date from, date to and an input field ) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to retrieve data from mysql database table based on three input search parameters like `date from`,`date to` , and input text field like `location`,`customer id`. Please provide some code how to do this?

**Screen shot of table:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've stored the input prams in following variables...

```
$date_from
$date_to
$location
$customer_id
```

and you have a table called customers, structured

id
name
email
location
date_from
date_to

...you could then build your query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM customers where id = $customer_id AND location = '$location' AND date_from = $date_from AND date_to = $date_to";
```

PS: I had images disabled on my browser so I couldn't see the  screenshot you posted, instead I just generated a table structure as an example.